# How to load Images with image adapter to gallery from server

Tags: android, image, gallery

I have the following two classes 
This is the Image Adapter class:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context myContext;

private int[] myImageIds = { R.drawable.member, R.drawable.me,
               R.drawable.member, R.drawable.me};


public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    this.myContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return this.myImageIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, 
        ViewGroup parent) {


    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this.myContext);
    iv.setImageResource(this.myImageIds[position]);

    // Image should be scaled somehow
    //iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
    //iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);         
    //iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    //iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    //iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    //iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_END);
    iv.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(300, 300));

    return iv;
}}
```

And this is the class wich holds the gallery:

```
public class GreekStore0 extends Activity{

Gallery myGallery;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.store);
    myGallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);

    myGallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
}}
```

What i want to do is instead of getting the images from the drawablefolder to get them from a server.
For now in the development i want this server to be my localhost. I am using XAMPP to manage a database that is synced with the application in an other part.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to not reinvent the wheel and instead use a powerful high quality library for this that handles this both smoothly (code and performance wise), such as Square's excellent open source Picasso library.

Example usage:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Picasso is available here:

http://square.github.io/picasso/

Or use the Smoothie library for ListView/GridView specifically:

https://github.com/lucasr/smoothie